# Does changing the hidden property of a UILabel also turn it's accessibility off?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, hidden, uiaccessibility

I created a `UILabel` and set it to `hidden` from the Attributes inspector, equivalent to :

```
self.hiddenLabel.hidden = YES;
```

It has an `accessibilityLabel` String set to it :

```
self.hiddenLabel.accessibilityLabel = @"Hidden Label";
```

Now, on doing so, when I inspect the `self.hiddenLabel.isAccessibilityElement` property, I oddly find it turned off. Also, when I look at `self.hiddenLabel.accessibilityElementsHidden`, I find that it is set to true.

So now, for accessibility to pick it up, I need to manually set `self.hiddenLabel.isAccessibilityElement` to `YES`. Can someone tell me why this behavior is seen or how I could circumvent it or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably observing the default accessibility behavior of `UILabel`. To implement custom behavior, override the methods defined in the [`UIAccessibility`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/) protocol. That said, if you're trying to create faux accessibility elements with no visible presence, it's more correct and consistent to adopt [`UIAccessibilityElement`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityElement_Class/index.html) than it is to customize UIKit controls.